# various ways of asking someone to go out for dinner

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Do these following sentences sound natural to an English native speaker?

> 1. let's go out for dinner sometimes soon
> 2. Let’s go have dinner sometimes soon
> 3. Let’s get together and have dinner sometimes soon
> 4. Let’s go grab dinner sometimes soon

Specifically, I know colloquially we use `grab` to mean that we eat something, but does it also apply to the occasion where we need to sit down for a nice dinner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction: ***Sometime*** soon.

If I were inviting a woman out for a nice dinner, I would not use "grab." If I were to use that expression, I would use it more for eating at a fast food type place rather than a nice restaurant. If I did use it, I would use it more for a situation where perhaps we are already doing something together, sightseeing or whatever. "Are you hungry? Why don't we grab a bite to eat?" In other words, it's better used for spur-of-the-moment type situations where little or no notice has been given to the potential invitee.

Also, if I were inviting someone out, and I was really eager for it to happen, I would name a definite time. I would say something like: "Let's go out to eat. Could go this Friday night?" "Sometime soon" leaves it hanging.

Your first three answers are more appropriate in my opinion (keeping in mind what I said about "sometime") for asking someone to what you call "a nice dinner."